# Expressing $dx$ in terms of $d \theta$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, coordinate-systems

Given $x^2$ + $y^2$ = $r^2$ (right-angled triangle with angle $\theta$) and $dx$ as a small length of $x$,

we know that $x$ = $y$$cot \theta$.

However, the answer scheme proceeds to explain that:

$x$ = $y$$cot \theta$ => $dx$ = -$y$($csc^2 \theta$)$d \theta$

and I completely do not understand how they can derive the latter from the former. Can anyone help?

Comment: If you're a physicist, then you just differentiate both sides with respect to $x$, and by using the product rule and the chain rule you get $$\frac{dx}{dx} = y\cdot \frac{d\cot \theta}{d\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dx}$$Calculate the derivative of $\cot\theta$, and finally multiply by $dx$ on both sides and you're done.

Comment: @Arthur: But who depends on $\theta$ here? If $x$ does, then $y$ does too, because $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$. I find the question totally not clear, since it is not clear to me which are the functions and which are their arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: $$(\cot(x))'=\frac{-\sin^2(x)-\cos^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)}=-1-\cot^2(x)$$